# How to enter a repeating decimal in Mathematica

Tags: number-representation, arithmetic, output-formatting

I don't understand how to manipulate numbers with repeating decimal in Wolfram Mathematica language.

For example `0.3...` does not work as input and I don't see how to add a vinculum to indicate the repeating part either. There's no manual or something on the issue on the net. Something strange and unusable `0.12(34)^_ (repeating decimal)` is given by Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: It's probably easiest to just add it as a fractional term if you need arbitrary precision `12/100+(34/99)/100`.

Answer (score 31):

Indeed, there is no direct method to input a repeating decimal. The closest you can get is to input the repeating digits into [`FromDigits[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromDigits.html):

$$0.\overline{142857}$$

```
FromDigits[{{{1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7}}, 0}]
   1/7
```

$$0.\overline{3}$$

```
FromDigits[{{{3}}, 0}]
   1/3
```

$$0.1\overline{6}$$

```
FromDigits[{{1, {6}}, 0}]
   1/6
```

Of course, this also applies for e.g. repeating binary representations:

$${0.000\overline{1100}}_2$$

```
FromDigits[{{0, 0, 0, {1, 1, 0, 0}}, 0}, 2]
   1/10
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16):

Use the [`ResourceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction.html) [`RepeatingDecimalToRational`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RepeatingDecimalToRational/):

```
ResourceFunction["RepeatingDecimalToRational"][0.3, 1]

(* 1/3 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if WolframAlpha notation is identical with Mathematica, although in the question you look like you used the `0.12343434...` (3 dots), but in WolframAlpha (this is how I got to this question), you can use:

```
0.123434..
```

for `0.12(34)`

[WolframAlpha](https://wolframalpha.com/) and Mathematica should be the *same software under the covers* having Steven Wolfram as creator. If not, I will let it as reference for those looking for WolframAlpha equivalent.

Comment: This may be not a repeating decimal. You do not know what numbers come after.

Comment: For what it's worth, `0.123434..` does NOT work in Mathematica to represent a number with repeating digits. The expression `0.123434 ..` just the same as `Repeated[0.123434]` which is a pattern. I.e. `MatchQ[{0.123434, 0.123434, 0.123434}, {Repeated[0.123434]}]` would return `True`.

Comment: Thank you [@lericr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/84894/lericr). I understand and agree with you (+1). Do you think it worth leaving this answer only for context and equivalence for WolframAlpha ? Thank you [@Валерий Заподовников](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/82985/%d0%92%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2) (+1)!

Comment: My recommendation would be to delete it, but it's a judgment call and I'm fine either way.